# Zlib Inflate Error Ignorance and Initiating from Pointer

Tags: delphi-2010, zlib

I was again working on a program related to ZLIB when I noticed that my program needs a function that Initiates Inflate from given position (Might be Hex or Hexadecimal) & inflates till the stream ends. Also, I need a modified EZDecompressionError so that it doesn't make the program close when it occurs, instead just a Boolean comes out that error has occurred.

The external libraries I'm using are ZlibEX & ZlibExAPI.

I'm in a bit of a hurry as I need to submit this project as my term project in MIT so thanks for all your efforts in advance. ^_^

Greetings
Zenith

Comment: What do you want us to do?

Comment: Sir, I require to read file byte by byte & process all of them with Zlib. So, I needed a suggestion on the function to use which read from that byte till the stream ends or returns error in a boolean not by causing my program to show "Stopped working"

Comment: You should write the compressed length to the file

Comment: Well, I was chasing this theory to sequentially increase the offset and decrease the size of the compressed size till it reaches 0.
Can you please please help me with that Sir David